# deserializing data best practices

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, serialization, deserialization

I have been given the task of deserializing some data. The data has all been munged into a string which is in the following format:

`InternalNameA8ValueDisplay NameA¬InternalNameB8ValueDisplay NameB¬` etc etc.

(ie, it has an internal name, '8', the value, the display name, followed by '¬' **). for example,  you'd have `FirstName8JoeFirst Name¬`

I have no control over how this data is serialized, its legacy stuff.

I've thought of doing a bunch of splits on the string, or breaking it up into a char array and splitting down the text that way. But this just seems horrible. This way there is too much that could go wrong (e.g, if the value of a phone number (for example), could begin with '8'.

What I want to know is what peoples' approaches to this would be? Is there anything more clever i can do to break the data down

**note:** '¬' isn't actually the character, it looks more like an arrow pointing left. but I'm away from my machine at the moment. Doh!

Thanks.

Comment: The data pattern is ugly, so the parsing solution is not going to be pretty.  What separates the fields?

Comment: I think you are reading the binary data as text, therefore you have so ugly(and almost impossible to parse) string.

Comment: I think you're too late for "best practices" here. You've inherited a strange format that can't be changed, so your method of handling it is likely going to be strange as well. My advice would be to find a way to parse the data that is *correct*, and then make that code look as nice as possible.

Comment: Yep, its horrible. Looks like its going to have to be something similarly ugly to deserialize then. Thanks guys.

Comment: Thanks guys. But as stated I'm stuck with this text how it is. @I4V if you're saying we're reading the binary data as text, do you know of a way to get it back as raw data and find another way to extract the data?

Comment: @villamartin If you put the *original data* (eg, original file) to somewhere, i can take a look at it. (not the one,  after you have read/processed it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using splits, I would recommend using a simple state machine. Walk over each characters until you hit a delimiter, then you know you're on the next field. That takes care of issues like an "8" in a phone number.

NOTE - untested code ahead.

```
var fieldValues = new string[3];
var currentField = 0;
var line = "InternalNameA8ValueDisplay NameA¬InternalNameB8ValueDisplay NameB¬";

foreach (var c in line)
{
    if (c == '8' && currentField == 0)
    {
        currentField++; continue;
    }

    if (c == '¬')
    {
        currentField++; continue;
    }

    fieldValues[currentField] += c;
}
```

Dealing with wonky formats - always a good time!

Good luck,
Erick